# I wish to execute .exe file from my php program. I am using Windows 7 , WAMP on my local machine

Tags: php

I wish to execute .exe file from my php program. I am using Windows 7 , WAMP on my local machine. My code is -

```
exec('C:/wamp/www SkypeSetup.exe');

/*AND*/



 $answer = shell_exec("C:/wamp/www/SkypeSetup.exe -args");
 echo $answer;
```

But above code is not working. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what output are you getting? can you post it?

Comment: getting white browser

Comment: :try to execute the script through command line, or enable the error reporting, or check the error log... you may see the actual error

Comment: are these functions enabled in your php.ini? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Comment: i am able to execute it with cmd but could not do it with php. can anyone please help me out. please its urgent.thank you

Comment: even i made changes in php.ini file for exec "magic_quotes_runtime = on".Can anyone tell me is there anything else i need to change.thank you